# How to make flexcroll to work with wordpress post thumbnails?

Tags: wordpress, scroll, thumbnails

I'm trying to make a div where I'm calling the post thumbnail, to recognize flexcroll, but it's not working. It works with text, but not in this way:

```
<div class="post">
<?php query_posts( 'p=77' );
while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
<div id="contcell" class="flexcroll">
<div id="thumb" ><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'full'); ?></div></div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
```

And these are the related css:

```
#contcell {width:1116px; height:300px; overflow:auto;}
.thumb {width:1116px; height:768px;}
```

If I disable flexcroll class, the browser default scrollers works.
Any ideas? Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. It wasn't a matter of what to load inside the flexcroll div, but clearing the floats of its content. Found it in the flexcroll user guide examples:

```
<div id='mycustomscroll' class='flexcroll'>

<img src="mypicture.jpg" width="100" height="100" class="floated" />

<img src="mypicture.jpg" width="100" height="100" class="floated" />

<img src="mypicture.jpg" width="100" height="100" class="floated" />

<img src="mypicture.jpg" width="100" height="100" class="floated" />

<!-- we clear our floats using the following div, check out the CSS for it-->

<div class="clearfloat"></div>

</div>
```

And the css:

```
.clearfloat {
clear:both; height:0px;
line-height:0px; visibility: hidden;
}
```

It's all inside the code download folder. Not sure if I can put the direct link here, but it's easy to find it. Hope it helps someone.